# draw svg to canvas with canvg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, canvg

I use canvg for set svg file in canvas.
All is ok when I set svg url:

```
var canvas = doc.getCanvas(num);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawSvg("http://localhost:8084/manual.svg", 0, 0, width, height);
```

But when I try to write (it doesn't work):

```
context.drawSvg("data:image/svg+xml,"+svg, 0, 0, width, height);
```

where variable svg get manual.svg content.

Comment: Is the string 'svg' urlescaped? a way to test is to copy-paste the data URI to the normal addressfield in your browser. Does it display correctly then?

Comment: Erik, thanks for your reply. I solve that problem with drawImage function. Also it works quicker than drawSvg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+btoa(svgContent);
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

it's one variant to solve the problem.

Comment: what's in the variable svgContent? canvas, or context?

Comment: svgContent needs to be the outerHTML of the svg element (including the <svg> tag itself)